# Are circles in the xy-plane mapped into circles in the uv-plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a linear transformation on $R^2$: $x=a_1u+a_2v$, $y=b_1u+b_2v$. Prove that lines and circles in the xy-plane are mapped respectively into lines and circles in the uv-plane.
The lines are easy to prove. The problem I have is to prove circles.
Let $(x-c)^2+(y-d)^2=h^2$ be an arbitrary circle on xy-plane.
Then:
$$(a_1u+a_2v-c)^2+(b_1u+b_2v-d)^2=h^2$$
after I expand the square terms, the uv term will appear and can't be cancelled. Is this still a circle?

Comment: $a_1 = 1, a_2 = b_1 = 0, b_2 = 2$ makes the unit circle into an ellipse. So without more assumptions on $a_i$ and $b_i$, you can't say anything about circles, but ellipses are taken to (possibly degenerate) ellipses.

Comment: The two eigenvalues of the transformation matrix are the same when $(a_1-b_2)^2+4a_2b_1=0$.

Comment: The image of a circle under a general linear transformation is a line segment or ellipse. It will only be a circle if $\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \\ b_1 & b_2 \end{bmatrix}$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quadratic equation to describe a circle, two conditions are necessary and sufficient:

- the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ must be equal (and nonzero),
- there must be no $xy$ term.

This translates to the constraints

$$a_1^2+b_1^2=a_2^2+b_2^2,\\a_1a_2+b_1b_2=0$$ which describe two orthogonal vectors of equal length.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not the case that circles maps into circles.

Check $$x^2+ y^2=25$$ under $$x=3u+2v$$ and $$y=u-v$$ and you get $$10u^2+5v^2+10uv =25$$ which is not a circle.